# How can I update some columns table2 from table1 automatically after insert any row in table1 (SQL Server)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have `table1`:

```
id  name    ranking energy   
-------------------------------
222    tom      15      f            
333    sara     11      f    
333    sara     2       a      
111    jhon     4       h       
111    jhon     16      f    
333    sara     13      g    
222    tom      12      j
```

And `table2`:

```
id  name    ranking
-------------------
111 jhon    2
222 tom     1
333 sara    0
```

I want for any row insert to table1 automatically update the column `ranking` in table2.

I think I should use the trigger but I do not know how?

I use below code but not work:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Table1Trigger   
ON Table1 
AFTER INSERT
BEGIN
    UPDATE Table2 
    SET ranking = Table1.ranking 
    WHERE Table1.id = Table2.id;
END;
```

Comment: What does "not work" mean? Why is your `TRIGGER` not referencing the `inserted` pseudo table? What is the object `Table1` in context of the `TRIGGER`? There's no `FROM` and only `Table2` is defined in the `UPDATE` clause, so `table1` has no meaning.

Comment: Is the name of the first column of your table1 "id_p" or just "id"? In your overview, you named it "id_p", but in your trigger "id". Did you have a look on a documentation like this one? https://www.tutorialgateway.org/after-insert-triggers-in-sql-server/ I think they can help much more.

Comment: I edit column id in table 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you actually want this:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.Table1Trigger
ON dbo.Table1
AFTER INSERT
AS --AS was missing
BEGIN

    UPDATE T2
    SET ranking = i.ranking
    FROM dbo.Table2 T2 
         JOIN inserted i ON T2.id = i.id;

END;
```

`Table1` in your attempt had no context; there was no object within the query defined as `Table1`. Also, however, it is highly unlikely you want to use **every** row in the table `Table1`, and rather just the rows that were inserted (which are in the pseudo table `inserted`).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the trigger, we can use an OUTPUT CLAUSE

```
DECLARE @TmpTable TABLE (ID INT, ranking VARCHAR(100))

INSERT TestTable (ID, TEXTVal)
OUTPUT Inserted.ID ,Inserted.TEXTVal INTO @TmpTable
VALUES (2,'SecondVal')

UPDATE T2
  SET ranking = i.ranking
  FROM dbo.Table2 T2 
     JOIN @TmpTable i ON T2.id = i.id;
```